# Oblong shape with css/html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display text inside series of spans. Like this:

[image]

Text length inside spans can vary.

What I want is to have span shape like oblong, like having semicircles at both ends.

I have tried using borderRadius, but not sure if it would work with span length varying.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Use `border-radius: 99999px`.

Comment: And maybe have to add a little padding to the left and right of each span so the text doesn't overflow from the background when the edges are curved?